# Merge two multidimensional arrays and sum values if same ids exists in both array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge, sum

I would like to merge two multidimensional arrays and sum their values (league tables), but only if the "clubid" value of second array exists in first array. Important: New array "form" value will be contained the form (team form) value of second array and form value of first array  (if 1st array form value is W, L, D and 2nd array value is D, L, D then new array form value should be D, L, D, W, L D )

First Array:

```
    array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Midtjylland',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '2',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '21',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '3',
    'F' => '42',
    'A' => '14',
    'GD' => '28',
    'Pts' => '65',
    'form' => 'W,L,W,W,W,W,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,L,D,W,W,W,D,W,W,W,W,W',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'København',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '1',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '18',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '6',
    'F' => '47',
    'A' => '29',
    'GD' => '18',
    'Pts' => '56',
    'form' => 'W,W,L,W,D,L,W,W,W,W,L,W,W,W,L,W,D,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,W',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'AGF',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '9',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '14',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '7',
    'F' => '42',
    'A' => '28',
    'GD' => '14',
    'Pts' => '47',
    'form' => 'W,W,D,L,D,W,W,D,W,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,D,L,L,L,D',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Brøndby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '4',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '13',
    'D' => '3',
    'L' => '10',
    'F' => '47',
    'A' => '37',
    'GD' => '10',
    'Pts' => '42',
    'form' => 'L,W,D,W,L,W,D,L,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,L,L,W,L,L,W,W,L,W,D,W',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Nordsjælland',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '7',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '12',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '9',
    'F' => '48',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '13',
    'Pts' => '41',
    'form' => 'L,W,D,W,W,W,W,L,D,W,D,L,L,W,D,L,W,L,W,L,W,D,L,W,L,W',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'AaB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '6',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '11',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '10',
    'F' => '44',
    'A' => '33',
    'GD' => '11',
    'Pts' => '38',
    'form' => 'L,D,W,L,W,W,L,D,D,W,D,L,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,W,L,W,L,W,D,L',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Randers',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '8',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '10',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '39',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '4',
    'Pts' => '35',
    'form' => 'L,L,D,L,W,D,W,L,W,L,D,W,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,D,D,L',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Horsens',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '10',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '10',
    'D' => '4',
    'L' => '12',
    'F' => '25',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-19',
    'Pts' => '34',
    'form' => 'W,W,W,L,L,L,W,D,W,L,W,D,L,W,L,D,L,D,W,L,L,L,W,L,W,L',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'OB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '3',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '9',
    'D' => '6',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '34',
    'A' => '30',
    'GD' => '4',
    'Pts' => '33',
    'form' => 'W,L,D,D,D,L,L,D,L,L,L,W,W,L,W,W,L,W,D,D,L,W,W,L,W,L',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Lyngby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '34',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '9',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '12',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '45',
    'GD' => '-14',
    'Pts' => '32',
    'form' => 'D,L,L,L,W,L,W,D,D,D,W,L,W,L,D,W,W,L,L,W,L,L,W,L,L,W',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'SønderjyskE',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '11',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '6',
    'D' => '9',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-13',
    'Pts' => '27',
    'form' => 'D,L,D,L,L,W,L,W,L,D,L,L,L,L,W,W,D,D,D,L,D,D,L,W,D,W',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Hobro',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '13',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '14',
    'L' => '9',
    'F' => '25',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '-10',
    'Pts' => '23',
    'form' => 'D,W,D,D,L,L,D,D,D,L,D,L,D,L,L,L,D,W,L,D,D,L,W,D,D,D',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Esbjerg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '5',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '4',
    'D' => '6',
    'L' => '16',
    'F' => '22',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-22',
    'Pts' => '18',
    'form' => 'L,D,D,L,L,W,L,L,L,W,L,D,L,L,L,D,W,L,L,D,W,L,L,L,D,L',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Silkeborg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '33',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '7',
    'L' => '16',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '55',
    'GD' => '-24',
    'Pts' => '16',
    'form' => 'D,L,W,D,D,L,L,W,L,L,L,L,D,W,L,L,L,L,L,D,D,D,L,L,L,L',
  ),
)
```

Second Array:

```
    array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'SønderjyskE',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '11',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '1',
    'F' => '6',
    'A' => '5',
    'GD' => '1',
    'Pts' => '11',
    'form' => 'D,D,W,W,L,W',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Silkeborg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '33',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '1',
    'L' => '2',
    'F' => '12',
    'A' => '4',
    'GD' => '8',
    'Pts' => '10',
    'form' => 'W,W,L,L,D,W',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'OB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '3',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '1',
    'L' => '2',
    'F' => '9',
    'A' => '12',
    'GD' => '-3',
    'Pts' => '10',
    'form' => 'L,D,W,W,W,L',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Lyngby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '34',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '0',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '4',
    'F' => '3',
    'A' => '9',
    'GD' => '-6',
    'Pts' => '2',
    'form' => 'D,L,L,L,D,L',
  ),
)
```

So in the new Array I would like to store sums of 1st of 2nd array, but only if id values of second array exists in first array)

New array should be:

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [Team] => OB
            [country] => dk
            [clubid] => 3
            [P] => 32
            [W] => 12
            [D] => 7
            [L] => 13
            [F] => 43
            [A] => 42
            [GD] => 1
            [Pts] => 43
            [form] => L,D,W,W,W,L,W,L,D,D,D,L,L,D,L,L,L,W,W,L,W,W,L,W,D,D,L,W,W,L,W,L
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
            [Team] => SønderjyskE
            [country] => dk
            [clubid] => 11
            [P] => 32
            [W] => 9
            [D] => 11
            [L] => 12
            [F] => 37
            [A] => 49
            [GD] => -12
            [Pts] => 38
            [form] => D,D,W,W,L,W,D,L,D,L,L,W,L,W,L,D,L,L,L,L,W,W,D,D,D,L,D,D,L,W,D,W
        )

  [2] => Array
        (
            [Team] => Lyngby
            [country] => dk
            [clubid] => 34
            [P] => 32
            [W] => 9
            [D] => 7
            [L] => 16
            [F] => 34
            [A] => 54
            [GD] => -20
            [Pts] => 34
            [form] => D,L,L,L,D,L,D,L,L,L,W,L,W,D,D,D,W,L,W,L,D,W,W,L,L,W,L,L,W,L,L,W
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Team] => Silkeborg
            [country] => dk
            [clubid] => 33
            [P] => 32
            [W] => 6
            [D] => 8
            [L] => 18
            [F] => 43
            [A] => 59
            [GD] =>-16
            [Pts] => 26
            [form] => W,W,L,L,D,W,D,L,W,D,D,L,L,W,L,L,L,L,D,W,L,L,L,L,L,D,D,D,L,L,L,L
        )
```

I hope someone could help for me, because I have no idea how could I do this. Many thanks.

Comment: Well you wrote the spec, now all you need to do is write the code!

Comment: do you have any issue with your function (codes) or just you need a function for that ? 
if you have a function please share it here with us to help you.

Comment: I don't know which is the best solution. My idea: First filter of 1st array (second array's clubid exists) - but I don't know how. Then sum the values of these arrays (but skip the form values). Then merge the form values of array 2 and array 1. What do you think, it is good?

Comment: Post the arrays as output from an `var_export()` so they are easy to use to test an answer please

Comment: I have posted the output from var_export (array1 and array2), I hope this could help for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the 2 arrays to have the clubid as their key, which makes them easily checkable. Then do whatever you want to to add etc the parts of the clubs data in a new array.

```
$arr1 =     array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Midtjylland',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '2',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '21',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '3',
    'F' => '42',
    'A' => '14',
    'GD' => '28',
    'Pts' => '65',
    'form' => 'W,L,W,W,W,W,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,L,D,W,W,W,D,W,W,W,W,W',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'København',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '1',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '18',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '6',
    'F' => '47',
    'A' => '29',
    'GD' => '18',
    'Pts' => '56',
    'form' => 'W,W,L,W,D,L,W,W,W,W,L,W,W,W,L,W,D,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,W',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'AGF',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '9',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '14',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '7',
    'F' => '42',
    'A' => '28',
    'GD' => '14',
    'Pts' => '47',
    'form' => 'W,W,D,L,D,W,W,D,W,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,W,D,L,L,L,D',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Brøndby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '4',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '13',
    'D' => '3',
    'L' => '10',
    'F' => '47',
    'A' => '37',
    'GD' => '10',
    'Pts' => '42',
    'form' => 'L,W,D,W,L,W,D,L,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,L,L,W,L,L,W,W,L,W,D,W',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Nordsjælland',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '7',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '12',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '9',
    'F' => '48',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '13',
    'Pts' => '41',
    'form' => 'L,W,D,W,W,W,W,L,D,W,D,L,L,W,D,L,W,L,W,L,W,D,L,W,L,W',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'AaB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '6',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '11',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '10',
    'F' => '44',
    'A' => '33',
    'GD' => '11',
    'Pts' => '38',
    'form' => 'L,D,W,L,W,W,L,D,D,W,D,L,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,W,L,W,L,W,D,L',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Randers',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '8',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '10',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '39',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '4',
    'Pts' => '35',
    'form' => 'L,L,D,L,W,D,W,L,W,L,D,W,L,L,W,W,W,W,W,L,L,L,W,D,D,L',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Horsens',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '10',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '10',
    'D' => '4',
    'L' => '12',
    'F' => '25',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-19',
    'Pts' => '34',
    'form' => 'W,W,W,L,L,L,W,D,W,L,W,D,L,W,L,D,L,D,W,L,L,L,W,L,W,L',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'OB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '3',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '9',
    'D' => '6',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '34',
    'A' => '30',
    'GD' => '4',
    'Pts' => '33',
    'form' => 'W,L,D,D,D,L,L,D,L,L,L,W,W,L,W,W,L,W,D,D,L,W,W,L,W,L',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Lyngby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '34',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '9',
    'D' => '5',
    'L' => '12',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '45',
    'GD' => '-14',
    'Pts' => '32',
    'form' => 'D,L,L,L,W,L,W,D,D,D,W,L,W,L,D,W,W,L,L,W,L,L,W,L,L,W',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'SønderjyskE',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '11',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '6',
    'D' => '9',
    'L' => '11',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-13',
    'Pts' => '27',
    'form' => 'D,L,D,L,L,W,L,W,L,D,L,L,L,L,W,W,D,D,D,L,D,D,L,W,D,W',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Hobro',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '13',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '14',
    'L' => '9',
    'F' => '25',
    'A' => '35',
    'GD' => '-10',
    'Pts' => '23',
    'form' => 'D,W,D,D,L,L,D,D,D,L,D,L,D,L,L,L,D,W,L,D,D,L,W,D,D,D',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Esbjerg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '5',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '4',
    'D' => '6',
    'L' => '16',
    'F' => '22',
    'A' => '44',
    'GD' => '-22',
    'Pts' => '18',
    'form' => 'L,D,D,L,L,W,L,L,L,W,L,D,L,L,L,D,W,L,L,D,W,L,L,L,D,L',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Silkeborg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '33',
    'P' => '26',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '7',
    'L' => '16',
    'F' => '31',
    'A' => '55',
    'GD' => '-24',
    'Pts' => '16',
    'form' => 'D,L,W,D,D,L,L,W,L,L,L,L,D,W,L,L,L,L,L,D,D,D,L,L,L,L',
  ),
);

$arr2 =     array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'SønderjyskE',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '11',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '1',
    'F' => '6',
    'A' => '5',
    'GD' => '1',
    'Pts' => '11',
    'form' => 'D,D,W,W,L,W',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Silkeborg',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '33',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '1',
    'L' => '2',
    'F' => '12',
    'A' => '4',
    'GD' => '8',
    'Pts' => '10',
    'form' => 'W,W,L,L,D,W',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'OB',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '3',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '3',
    'D' => '1',
    'L' => '2',
    'F' => '9',
    'A' => '12',
    'GD' => '-3',
    'Pts' => '10',
    'form' => 'L,D,W,W,W,L',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Team' => 'Lyngby',
    'country' => 'dk',
    'clubid' => '34',
    'P' => '6',
    'W' => '0',
    'D' => '2',
    'L' => '4',
    'F' => '3',
    'A' => '9',
    'GD' => '-6',
    'Pts' => '2',
    'form' => 'D,L,L,L,D,L',
  ),
);

//convert the arrays to have a usable key i.e. the clubid
foreach( $arr1 as $a){
    $t1[$a['clubid']] = $a;
}
//make an array with a usable key i.e. the clubid
foreach( $arr2 as $a){
    $t2[$a['clubid']] = $a;
}

foreach ($t2 as $k=>$t) {
    if (isset($t1[$k])){
        //$tmp = $t;
        $tmp = $t;
        $tmp['form'] = $t['form'] . ',' . $t2[$k]['form'];

        $tmp['P'] = $t2[$k]['P'] + $t['P'];
        $tmp['W'] = $t2[$k]['W'] + $t['W'];
        $tmp['D'] = $t2[$k]['D'] + $t['D'];
        $tmp['L'] = $t2[$k]['L'] + $t['L'];
        $tmp['F'] = $t2[$k]['F'] + $t['F'];
        $tmp['A'] = $t2[$k]['A'] + $t['A'];
        $tmp['GD'] = $t2[$k]['GD'] + $t['GD'];
        $tmp['Pts'] = $t2[$k]['Pts'] + $t['Pts'];

        $new[] = $tmp;
    } else {
        $new[] = $t;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, your code is working, but I need only one modification: In the new array I need just teams of second array (that's why I wanted to filter first array based on second array clubid) with the same sorting method (pts, GD, W DESC)

Comment: OK couple of minutes

Comment: Do you not want the Played and Won etc etc added up from both?

Comment: Subtle change, just switched the array I look at first to t2

Comment: I have changed one row to show the exact form:  $tmp['form'] = $t['form'] . ',' . $t2[$k]['form'];    It is good solution if I order this array (sort by pts, GD, W desc)?

Comment: Right forgot about that one when I did the mod

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner / more concise way.  Declare the output array based on the second array and apply the grouping first level keys.

Then iterate the first array and only concatenate or add values when the first array's clubid is found in the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KO04i))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr2 as $array) {
    $result[$array['clubid']] = $array;
}
foreach ($arr1 as $array) {
    $clubId = $array['clubid'];
    if (isset($result[$clubId])) {
        $result[$clubId]['form'] .= ',' . $array['form'];         // concat
        foreach (['P', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'F', 'A', 'GD', 'Pts'] as $tally) {
            $result[$clubId][$tally] += $array[$tally];           // add
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: You are welcome.  I wouldn't have posted it unless I felt it was a superior answer.  It wouldn't make sense to post a less valuable late answer.  I am not a Fastest Gun In The West (FGITW) user, so my answers are often overlooked by people who care about the posting timestamp.